# Renaming images in specific order

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

This is my problem: I have a folder with 500 images named:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

and so on..

I copied that folder and now I need to rename those same pictures from 501 to 1000 but in order like this:

```
1.jpg  becomes    501.jpg
2.jpg  becomes    502.jpg
3.jpg  becomes    503.jpg          
....
```

When I use my standard renaming command:

```
i=501;for img in $(find . -iname '*.jpg'); do echo -n "Converting $img"; mv $img $i.jpg  && echo $i && ((i++)); done
```

It orders images from 501 to 1000 but they are all scattered:

```
23.jpg becomes 501.jpg,    
66.jpg becomes 502.jpg 
...
```

(they are in right order, but it mixes them up)

I know it's probably one command I'm missing...

Comment: Use 2 variables i and j mv $i.jpg $j.jpg and increment your variables.

Comment: thank you, hope you'll figure it out. I searched but didn't find the answer..

Comment: Just curious, the original names, in what range are they? Should the original number just be renamed + 500?

Comment: Yes Jacob you +500.    I am trying to write what bodhi told me but I am not so good in lnux, I killed my self to write the rename command above :D

Comment: My poor laptop is heavily occupied atm, but if no satisfying answer comes up (which I doubt :) ) and if you won't manage, I'll post a tiny python script tonight.

Comment: Guys pomsky solved it. Thank you all very much you are very kind and you saved my ass. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try **Thunar**, which is the default file manager for Xfce. It is very lightweight and comes with a handy bulk renaming tool. You can install Thunar by running the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

You'll probably be able to install from Ubuntu Software too.

### How to use the utility

1. Once you've installed Thunar, launch the **Bulk Rename** utility.
2. Click on the **+** icon and add the files you want to rename in the proper order.
3. Click on the drop-down box just below the list of selected files and select **Numbering**. Click on the box next to it and select **Name Only**.
4. In the "*Start With:*" box enter 501, leave the "*Text:*" box empty. You should see the preview of the changes in the *New Name* column.
5. To apply the changes click on the **Rename Files** button.

Besides *Numbering* this utility supports the following actions:

- Insert Date / Time
- Insert / Overwrite
- Remove Characters
- Search & Replace
- Uppercase / Lowercase

Comment: Thanks man you're the MVP! I only have  to add that I also needed to change  Text format to:  Text - Number.  (just in case anyone else use this)

Comment: To Switch fm to... perform a simple task seems overkill to me. Writing a simple nautilus script extension takes less time then switching fm.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm using Thunar just for the bulk rename tool along with Nautilus. Thunar is pretty light and doesn't seem to cause any conflict with Nautilus or other file managers.

Comment: If you don't want a second file manager, `pyrenamer` works perfectly and is what I use for bunk renames when I want a GUI to compare before/after output.

Answer (score 13):

The `find` command finds files in 'directory' order (`23.jpg`, `66.jpg`, ...). you could put a `|sort` after the find.

But your methods are overcomplex.

```
for i in $( seq 1 500 ) ; do
    j=$(( $i + 500 ))
    mv $i.jpg $j.jpg
done
```

Comment: `for i in {1..500}; do ...` would have bee easier.

Answer (score 11):

With `rename` command.

```
rename -n 's/^(\d+)/sprintf("%d",$1+500)/e' *.jpg
```

Or in pure `bash` and using [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
for FILE in *.jpg; do
    mv "$FILE" "$(( ${FILE%.jpg}+500 )).jpg" 
done
```

Answer (score 5):

If I've understood what you are asking correctly, I think you can do it using the default rename tool:

```
rename 's/^(\d+)/sprintf("%d",$1+500)/e' *.jpg -vn
```

You should remove the `-vn` (verbose - no action) switch after testing, to make the change effective.

Comment: How can one install this tool in Ubuntu? by default `rename` is linked to [`prename(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/prename.1.html) from the `perl` package which doesn't support all these command-line options.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You may be right. I couldn't find a current installation link (I haven't used it since about 2014). With the default rename tool, I think the regex expression should be `'s/^(\d+)/sprintf("%d",$1+500)/e'`. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is now a duplicate of [AFSHIN’s](/a/949818/175814).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sorry, what answer? The only other answers I can see are by pomsky & waltinator. Neither use rename (either version).

Comment: The direct link to the answer I mean is included in my previous comment.

Comment: That link isn't working. I get a Page not Found message. I only see  3 answers (including mine) to the question. (I'm viewing on the Android SE app atm).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64477/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-sempaiscuba).

Comment: +1 for bothering to describe switch utilization (and your reasoning in chat)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving this with just shell command

count=1;for i in `ls`; do  mv $i  CN$((count++)).${i##*.}; done